# laravel 5 nested category and nested sub category

Tags: php, laravel-5, categories, eloquent

Using Laravel 5.6, I am trying to display sub-category of a sub-category from a MySQL categories table. I want to pass the name and get all it's child categories irrespective of the parent.

**categories Table**

```
 id  | name              | cat_parent_id
 --- | ------------------| ------------- 
 1   | Parent - 1        | NULL 
 2   | Parent - 2        | NULL 
 3   | Child-1- P - 1    | 1 
 4   | Child-1- P - 2    | 2 
 5   | sCh-1-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 6   | sCh-2-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 7   | sCh-3-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 8   | sCh-4-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 9   | sCh-5-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4
```

**Desired Result**

return App\Category::where('name','Child-1- P - 2')->Children->get();

```
 id  | name              | cat_parent_id
 --- | ------------------| ------------- 
 5   | sCh-1-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 6   | sCh-2-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 7   | sCh-3-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 8   | sCh-4-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4 
 9   | sCh-5-Ch-1-P- 2   | 4
```

Comment: what is the question? having problem of define `children` relationship or .. ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to define the relationship myself, but it is not giving me the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well, to obtain `children` relationship you could use the following method on the `App\Category` model:

```php
// app/Category.php

public function children(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'cat_parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Then to obtain all children of the main category:

```php
use App\Category;

$children = Category::where('name','Child-1- P - 2')->first()->children;
```

And here is a supporting test with a factory:

```php
// database/factories/CategoryFactory.php

use App\Category;

$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $id = 1;
    return [
        'name' => 'Category '.$id++,
        'cat_parent_id' => null,
    ];
});

// tests/Unit/Models/CategoryTest.php

use App\Category;

/**
 * @test
 */
public function returns_associated_child_records()
{
    // create master records
    factory(Category::class, 3)->create();

    // get parent for the sub-categories
    $parent = $master->first();

    // create sub-categories
    foreach(range(1, 4) as $id) {
        factory(Category::class)->create([
            'name' => 'Sub category '.$id,
            'cat_parent_id' => $parent->id
        ]);
    }

    $this->assertEquals(
        ['Sub category 1', 'Sub category 2', 'Sub category 3', 'Sub category 4'],
        Category::where('name', $parent->name)->first()->children->pluck('name')->toArray()
    );
}
```

I'm working here on the assumption that category names will be unique - otherwise you'd have to loop over the collection of records.

Comment: Your assumption is correct !! The names will be unique.

Comment: @ Sebastian, I had to drop HasMany from the line to get the result. Otherwise, it was resulting in "Type error: Return value of App\Category::children() must be an instance of App\HasMany, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany returned".


public function children(): HasMany

Comment: Sorry - yes, this should be imported in your class as `use lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` and it will work fine.